# How to mark up an author with their pen name / pseudonym in Docbook 5?

Tags: docbook, docbook-5

Should I simply use another [`author`](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/author.html) element / tag with the [`role` attribute](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/ref-elements.html#common.attributes) set to `"pseudonym"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it fully depends on a processing logic you are going to implement and how exactly you want to work with the **pseudonym** metadata.

You may consider using an [othername](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/othername.html) or a [personname](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/personname.html) instead as a part of an [author](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/author.html) block. Probably it would be more flexible in many ways.

Comment: Didn't even think of that, thanks! I would go with `personname` as "_[the `othername` element is a generic wrapper for parts of an individual’s name](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/othername.html#element.db.othername_refsection1)_", and a pseudonym is a separate entity in my interpretation. (Then again, as you said, it depends on the logic employed:) I guess I would just list 2 `personname`s in a single `author`, right? (At least, [`author`'s content model](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/author.html) can be a sequence of `personname`s, if I interpreted it right.)

Comment: Actually you need to think about not only processing logic involved, but also editing (authoring) workflow, as if multiple people involved in text authoring it would be a quite complex way to explain why you use several `personname`'s and which one someone needs to use for what purpose. It is recommended to look at and further analyze your particular authoring model that is, in fact, a subset of more general DocBook model.

Comment: Thank you for the food for thought! I am just naively trying to translate a short (ca. 12 A4 pages) novella whose author published it under a pseudonym, but later started publishing under his own name.  Only doing this as a personal exercise, so all this is not really necessary, but now I see that DocBook authoring goes deeper than syntax & semantics.